# Add spell check functionality to windows form textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have built a simple windows form in which a user can edit some text that saves and is portrayed on another form.  Now I want to add spell check to the original form where the user edits the text.  Any idea how to approach this?

Here's the windwos form code:

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        If txtEdit.Text = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please complete the notes textbox!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            value = txtEdit.Text
            Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Textbox (at least, in Winforms) does not have such an in-built functionality. You woulde have to rely on an external library or on another class/control supporting it (e.g., MS Word via Office Interop).

Comment: I believe that one is specific to vs-2008 only @HansPassant

Comment: It is not, still works fine in VS2013 with .NET 4.5.1